# showDialog() shows result without call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, messagebox, showdialog

I´ve got the following code-line to show a Window in a MessageBox:

```
MessageBox.Show(new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog().ToString());
```

The problem is, that when I close it, another MessageBox starts with `true` or `false`, but I never told it to do.
How can I fix that?

**Here´s more relevant code:**

```
                    string ganzes = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] allezeilen = ganzes.Split('\n');

                    for (int i = 0; i < allezeilen.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        string[] separated = allezeilen[i].Split(';');

                        String datum = separated[0];
                        String titel = separated[1];
                        if (titel.Contains('"'))
                        {
                            titel = titel.Replace('"', ' ');
                        }
                        String betrag = separated[3];
                        buchrep.bookFromElbaCSV(datum, titel, betrag, loginid);
                        //ElbaKostenstellen ek = new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid);
                        //ek.Show();
                       MessageBox.Show(new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog().ToString());
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show a form calling `ShowDialog` on it is enough, a call to `MessageBox.Show` is unnecessary. Try;

```
new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog();
```

instead of

```
MessageBox.Show(new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog().ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You told it when write this string

```
MessageBox.Show(new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog().ToString());
```

So you need to get message from ElbaKostenstellen without calling ShowDialog()

Answer (score 1):

lets look at

```
MessageBox.Show(new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog().ToString());
```

The first bit that gets evaluated is

```
new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog()
```

this shows the dialog and the execution of code is blocked until the dialog is closed.

then the

```
MessageBox.Show(...)
```

is executed and displays the string representation of the result of the previous dialog.

I suspect you do not need the `MessageBox.Show(..)`, just the `new ElbaKostenstellen(titel, loginid).ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the return value of ShowDialog is true or false.

As written here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Nullable A Nullable value of type Boolean
>   that specifies whether the activity was accepted (true) or canceled
>   (false). The return value is the value of the DialogResult property
>   before a window closes.